# Ext JS 4 and 5 difference

Tags: extjs

Can't find solution for such a simple problem. I have working application in  ExtJS 4 with such a button definition:

```
                    {
                        xtype:     'button',
                        text:      'Enter',
                        itemId:    'PRZ_ENTER',
                        margin:    '140 0 0 80',
                        baseCls:   'x-btn-default-large',
                        style:     'font-size: 18px; text-align: center',
                        width:      160
                    }
```

easy, working, etc. Now I try to transfer this code to Ext JS 5 environment and this definition isn't ok. Size of text isn't 18px but lower. Probably it's trivial but I can't find WHY and where can I look for info in that case?

Precisely in both cases position (center) and size (18px) properties of button definition are defined the same way but in ExtJS 4 it's ok and in ExtJS5 isn't:

In ExtJS 4 effect is the following:

[image]

In ExtJS 5 effect is the following:

[image]

Comment: What is the problem you will face after extjs conversion ?

Comment: Above definition is working in ExtJS 4 but not working in ExtJS 5. I mean (it is "style" definition problem) in ExtJS 4 I see 18px text in button but in ExtJS 5 text size is standard (10px I think).

Comment: I try to explain the situation in details (I forgot to show 'baseCls" property.